# C++ Interface declaration at compilation time?

Tags: templates, declaration, specialization

I'm trying to declare an arbitrary type variable (say `x`), which only requirement is that it contains a functor of a **known** signature, say `double operator()(double x)` to avoid the `std::function` overheads.

In particular, say the user should be able to initialize `x` to an object containing extra data + the required operator, but the declaration should remain ambivalent about the type, only stating the existence of the operator.

What I'm trying to may seem a little contrived, but it seems to me that there should be an easy way of achieving this, especially in modern C++, right?
I've seen template deduction, `auto` keyword and concepts, but I can't put this things together, to achieve what I need.

Pseudocode per request:

```
// auto should be instead some generic type specification that requires double operator(double) that I don't know how to write
auto x;

//Here's an example that would conform to x type specification above
struct Field
{
    double operator()(double time);
}
void main()
{
    x = Field();
}
```

Comment: Sorry... not clear to me what you exactly want. Please, could you show an example of intended use; maybe with a pseudo-code?

Comment: @max66 sure, just added!

Comment: I don't think it's possible so, directly. Also with a `std::function`. A member function of a class/struct is an object completely different from a normal function; you can't save a member function pointer to a generic function pointer. You can save a member function pointer but you have to know the class containing it.